# Reboot not possible: starting notify nfs peers of a restart

Tags: linux, systemd, nfs, suse

I hope someone has a good idea what is causing this problem.

I am running a NFSv3 server under SLES 12 SP4.

When trying to reboot the machine with `shutdown -r` the shutdown process hangs. The system immediately logs me out and can not be pinged anymore. 
On the local console I can see this message:

```
starting notify nfs peers of a restart...
```

Even after 20 minutes the status does not change.

I have a running snapshot of this VM so I can experiment with it.

I tried to set a timeout for `sm-notify` with the option `-m 1`, but it did not help.

Anyone has an idea?

Thank you very much in advance for any hint!

Comment: Can you please update your `/etc/fstab` o/p?